# Hawaiian ambiences 

Tags: sfx, ambience

Hey all
Anyone willing to swap some sfx?
Im in need of some ambiences from Hawaii. Preferably from smaller cities, countryside, and forests
Need it for an animation short taking place in Honolulu in the seventies, so nothing too fancy, modern or big.

Thanks alot.

Best wishes

Mikkel